# Concatenate ordered values in one single string

Tags: google-sheets, concatenate

I have a Google Spreadsheet where a person will add one name per row in a defined column (B). I need to generate a string like "`<p>Adam - Becky - John - Robert</p>`" in **one single** cell with alphabetically ordered names.

I can sort the names (in the second sheet) with the formula:

```
=sort(Sheet1!B:B, 1, TRUE)
```

But how can I concatenate these names in another cell (in the first sheet)?

Comment: As an aside, the sorting formula could be simply `=sort(Sheet1!B:B)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another solution thanks to [this post in the Google Support forums](https://support.google.com/docs/forum/AAAABuH1jm0UJPt6S5WFu0).

```
=arrayformula(concatenate(Proper(unique(upper(query(B2:B31,"select B where B!='' order by B asc",0))))&" - "))
```

which also capitalizes each (unique) name.

After this I generate my `<p>` with this:

```
="<p>- "&D10&"</p>"
```

(I added the hyphen at the beginning since I'll have one hyphen in the end)

Answer (score 4):

Use the JOIN() function:

```
=join(" - ",sort(Sheet1!B:B, 1, TRUE))
```

SORT() returns an array of values.
JOIN() concatenates an array with a joining string, in this case " - " without the quotes.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you Karl, this almost solves my problem!

My last issue is that, since I don't know how many names I will have, I'm sorting the entire column B. The conseguence of this is that the joined cell will show my sorted names with a list of "-" after them.

Like this:

> Adam - Becky - John - Robert -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -    *(and so on)*

I thought I could add to the cell next to the names this formula:

```
=IF(B2="","empty", "with_content")
```

Can I add to the join a condition like:

```
where C2 = "with_content"
```

?

Comment: Please note, this isn't a discussion forum. The Answer space should only be used to offer a solution to the original question. You should instead [edit your question](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/102189/edit) and include this new information.